# Cannot find a properties file by absolute path using Spring PropertySource

Tags: java, spring

My Spring application throws `FileNotFoundException` when I try to load external properties file using `@PropertySource` annotation.

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:/home/myuser/dev/app_name.properties")
public class ConfigurationClass {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public Connection getConnection() {
        ...
        String properties = env.getProperty("cbs.url");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: File is not present at that location, If you can share your path to file here.

Comment: Keep your app_name.properties on classpath i.e src/main/resources and give value like this @PropertySource(value = "app_name.properties").

Comment: @MohitSharma no I need to keep it in external path

Answer (score 0):

Try to give like this

`@PropertySource("file:/home/myuser/dev/app_name.properties")`

And make sure that **file available in that location**.
(or)
if you don't want **file not found Exception** when bootup your application then use below one
`@PropertySource("file:/home/myuser/dev/app_name.properties",ignoreResourceNotFound=true)`

Comment: The problem does not ignore it but how to fetch it correctly

Answer (score 0):

you can override `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean and provide file path there.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setLocations(new Resource[] {
        new FileSystemResource("/some/path/file.properties"),
        new FileSystemResource("/some/path/other-file.properties")
    });
    return configurer;
  }
```

It can be more flexible by passing the initial path as system param or env variable.

```
new FileSystemResource(System.getenv("CONFIG_PATH") + "/some/path/file.properties")
```

After overriding bean, your application configuration could be simple like this.(no need to specify property source)

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {
   ...

   //configurations can be accessed like this

   @Value("${config.variable.name}")
   private String configValue;

}
```

I hope this helps.